# TrueCrypt Macbook Pro Windows 7, won't boot from CD anymore

Tags: macbook, truecrypt

I tried installing Windows 7 as the first partition to TrueCrypt the system drive. Now it won't boot up anymore, it was working though. But now it says no boot partition available, and if I put the Windows or Mac OS X CD in, it won't boot from CD...

How do I force the Macbook Pro to boot from CD? No BIOS on MBP's apparently, etc...

Comment: if you feel like upvoting the post plz don't...i'm going for the unsung hero badge

Comment: that's why some of my posts are a bit snarky

Comment: aww i got upvoted anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a link on shortcut keys for boot options: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1533

C tells it to boot from optical drive

Comment: You are a life saver!

Comment: np, just looking for the check